# How to display many nested lists using PHP?

Tags: php

I was wondering how can you generate lists that have many nested lists deep using PHP.

How would you go about coding the PHP.

I'm stumped please help I'm new to PHP.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us that you're needing help and not asking us to do all the thinking for you.

Comment: Are you talking about multidimensional arrays?

Comment: I just don't no where to begin if I had the code I would of posted it for you.

Comment: @H2O, then post the psuedo code, explain what you're *trying* to do; give us an example of input and expected-output.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one method:

```
$tree = array(
  1,  2,
  array(31, 32, array(331, 332, 333)), array(341, 342),
  4, array(51, 52, 53, 54, array(551, 552, 553, array(5541, 5542))),
);
render_tree($tree);

function render_tree($tree, $indent = 0) {
  $space = str_repeat(' ', $indent);
  echo "$space<ul>\n";
  foreach ($tree as $node) {
    render_node($node, $indent + 2);
  }
  echo "$space</ul>\n";
}

function render_node($node, $indent) {
  $space = str_repeat(' ', $indent);
  if (is_array($node) && count($node) > 0) {
    echo "$space<li>\n";
    render_tree($node, $indent + 2);
    echo "$space</li>\n";
  } else {
    echo "$space<li>$node</li>\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**[Perhaps this function (print_r)](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)**

(This answers the question in the title. For the others, please consult a book/tutorial. Please use the resources available.)

Comment: *Technically* that answers any question of the form "How do I display _______ using PHP?"  But I doubt that's the answer the OP is seeking (though, who knows!).